# Why can't I access local variable in for loop (batch file) even with setlocal enabledelayedexpansion?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

Trying to access a custom local variable in a `FOR` loop within a batch file, I keep getting `ECHO is off`.
Despite that `enabledelayedexpansion` is set **and used** with `!_!`, as numerous guides suggest..

What may be wrong and how such trick should be performed in this case?

```
@ECHO OFF

for %%I IN (.) DO SET BatCurrPath = %%~fI
ECHO ---------------
ECHO %BatCurrPath%
ECHO ---------------

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /d %%d IN (*.*) DO (
    SET DirFound = %%d
    ECHO !DirFound!      <==== outputs "ECHO is off"
    ECHO %%d             <==== outputs child's dirname
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

for %%I IN (.) DO SET "BatCurrPath=%%~fI"
ECHO ---------------
ECHO %BatCurrPath%
ECHO ---------------

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /d %%d IN (*.*) DO (
    SET "DirFound=%%d"
    ECHO !DirFound!     
    ECHO %%d            
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Dont use spaces around `=` otherwise the spaces will become part of the variable name.